# what is the best practice for indexing the pages that can be edit or delete by authenticated users in any time?

Tags: seo, google-index

consider a website that authenticated users can create a content for example "bmw 1987 tuning for sale" and I need this pages to be index by google so if some one looking for this car in google can find this content. the problem is user can edit or delete this content any time and it's not like an article that can stay there forever. what should i do for thousands pages like this?
what happens if user delete the page after that google index that page?
I know I can not use webmaster tools for deleting this pages from index list any more and it was not rational way . should i use index after user create the page and change that to noindex after user delete the page? what about update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is used to websites like this, and has no trouble with the churn of new and deleted pages.

After the user deletes the page, you should make sure that your 404 "page not found" page (along with the 404 response code) is shown at that URL. Upon seeing the 404 at that URL, Google will gracefully remove the page from its index. This is the standard way to treat a deleted page, and is the recommended way to get it de-indexed from search engines.

As far as speeding this process up, you could consider using a sitemap. Google checks those regularly to find new and deleted pages.

Comment: so you say 404 does not hurt seo rank of the site? and for sitemap do you mean I should add content link to sitemap file when it's created and remove the link from sitemap after deleting the content ?

Comment: @Ali_Hr Using 404 on pages that you've deleted actually helps your SEO rather than hurting it. And you are correct about the sitemap.